# SQL Query to fetch emloyee name, salary where employee name is provided

Tags: mysql

For an `Employee` table with columns EmpId, Name and `Salary` Table with columns Id, EmpId, Salary, where EmpId of salary table is Foreign Key of Employee Table.
Is it possible to write a SQL query so that the result contains each employee's name and the salary of all employees provided by a employee name?

Sample Data

`Employee` Table

```
EmpId      Name       
 1         Alice      
 2         Bob        
 3         Charlie     
 4         Doug
```

`Salary` Table

Sample Data

```
 Id      EmpId       Salary 
 1         1       1000
 2         2       2000 
 3         3       3000 
 4         4       4000
```

Query I tried, but could not see, how I can write employee name say, Bob, where I want to fetch employee who have higher salary than Bob. Below query gives result with salary perspective, but how to fetch by employee name?

--Updated with Order By Clause, Thanks @Strawberry

```
    SELECT s.salary
    , e.empname 
    FROM
    test.employee as e, test.salary as s 
    WHERE s.empid = e.empid AND s.salary > 2000 
    ORDER BY s.Salary DESC 
    LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: "Is it possible to write a SQL query..."  Yes it's possible.

Comment: I understood on Inner Join Eric, but i clearly failed to get how can i filter with employee name, see like select e.name, s.salary from employee e Inner Join salary as s where e.empid = s.empid which will give the results of all employee but here how to use filter of emp name to check?

Comment: ... and note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Thanks, Although, my resultant was not to achieve in an order, so didn't used Order by Clause! Fairly, The LIMIT clause is used in the SELECT statement to constrain the number of rows to return. However, thanks for the tip, as i know, it is best practice to always use the LIMIT clause with the ORDER BY clause to constraint the result rows in unique order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query with which you can fetch the salary of Bob:

```
SELECT Salary
FROM salary
WHERE EmpId = 2;
```

Now you want to fetch all names and salaries of employees who have higher salary than what you fount with the query above. Therefore you will use the above query as a nested one in WHERE. Here you go:

```
SELECT employee.EmpId, employee.Name, salary.Salary
FROM employee
JOIN salary ON employee.EmpId = salary.EmpId
WHERE salary > (
                    SELECT Salary
                    FROM salary
                    WHERE EmpId = 2
                );
```

Edit - below in the comments you said that you want to filter by Name, not EmpId. Therefore you probably want to filtler with *WHERE Name="Bob"*. The problem is that usually names are not unique. Therefore you may have two people named "Bob". If that is the case, you must figure out a solution which salary to get - they may be different.

Here is an example query that will get the salary of person named "Bob" who have the highest salary among all Bobs, then filter the other employees to have higher salary than whatever is fount:

```
SELECT employee.EmpId, employee.Name, salary.Salary
FROM employee
JOIN salary ON employee.EmpId = salary.EmpId
WHERE salary > (
                    SELECT MAX(Salary)
                    FROM salary
                    WHERE EmpId IN (
                        SELECT EmpId
                        FROM employee
                        WHERE Name="Bob"
                    )
                );
```

Eventual issue may come if there is NO person named "Bob". The above query will return an empty set. If you want to print all people instead, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT employee.EmpId, employee.Name, salary.Salary
FROM employee
JOIN salary ON employee.EmpId = salary.EmpId
WHERE salary > (
                    SELECT IF(MAX(Salary) IS NULL, 0, MAX(Salary))
                    FROM salary
                    WHERE EmpId IN (
                        SELECT EmpId
                        FROM employee
                        WHERE Name="Bob"
                    )
                );
```

Now if there is no "Bob", it will still print all people with salaries above 0.

Comment: My query also returned the same thing. Query asked was to filter by emp name , say Bob, where i want to fetch employee earning more than bob in the employee table wrt to `salary` table.

Comment: Just change WHERE EmpId = 2 with WHERE Name = 'Bob'. Now what will happen if there are two people called "Bob". Let me know and we will work for a solution :)

Comment: yeah, that is what i also thought but was asked. Anyways distinct emp name, for now just in this case, no emp name is repeated twice.

Comment: If names are UNIQUE, then you can skip the MAX function.